# Benefit of JWTs over plain message + HMAC?

Tags: cryptography, jwt, api-design, hmac

I'm a software developer, not a cryptographer. I'm looking for a way by which customer programmers can send us authenticated claims via the frontend (we ship a browser-targeted JS API).

The usual answer in these cases, I guess, is JWTs. They solve my problem rather well: backend programmers of our customers can make some claims about one of their users, sign it with a secret key that we gave them, send it over via the frontend and we can verify the claims in our backend. This is elegant because it means that there is no direct dependency between their backend and ours and we can still share authenticated claims.

However, I have two beefs with JWTs:

1. Few languages have builtin support, so you need to install some library to do it, and hope that it's well implemented.
2. JWTs lately got a bad rep for their complexity, which I'm inclined to agree with because I think they're pretty complex too. Stuff about the `none` algorithm makes me worry that I might use them wrong or our customers might.

So I was thinking, against all "don't roll your own crypto" advice, what does a JWT really offer that an HMAC does not?

I.e. if I get my customers to do something like this:

token = base64_encode(claims) + hmac(claims, secret_key)

then that's basically a JWT without all the JSON or all the complexity, right? I see a bunch of upsides:

1. Many languages have built-in support for eg HMAC-SHA256, sufficiently guaranteeing crypto implementation quality.
2. Also, it's often a oneliner. Telling customers "copy&paste this line of code" is much more attractive than telling them "install this complicated library and hope it works"
3. None of the risks associated with JWT complexity.

Is there a reason to *not* do this? What, really, does a JWT offer over just a `message + hmac` type of scheme?

Comment: It offers a language- and algorithm- independent format which should enhance portability, just like any other decent standard. And that also means that somebody beside yourself has analyzed it for security weaknesses.

Comment: Obligatory: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): "*Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.*" The question is: Are you better than the best cryptographer? If not don't try.